# Getting the build agent to run 'dnvm install' and 'dnu restore' on every build

Tags: tfsbuild

I'm having issues getting an automated build working with dnx.  Doesn't the build need to run 'dnu restore' after getting the latest from source control?  My builds fail unless I manually log into the build machine and run 'dnu restore'.  Can't this step be part of the automated build?

Regards
Nick

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Usually dnx package files are not uploaded into source control by default. So you need to restore the packages before build. You can create a powershell script to perform a dun restore and invoke this script in your build process or configure it as pre-build event.

Code sample:

```
# run DNU restore on all project.json files in the src folder including 2>1 to redirect stderr to stdout for badly behaved tools
Get-ChildItem -Path $PSScriptRoot\src -Filter project.json -Recurse | ForEach-Object { & dnu restore $_.FullName 2>1 }
```

Reference from: [Build and Deploy your ASP.NET 5 Application to an Azure Web App](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vs/alm/build/azure/deploy-aspnet5)

[image]

**Update:**
For vNext build, you just need to add a "PowerShell" step at the top of your build definition to do this:
[image]
Remember to set the "Working folder" to the folder where "global.json" file is placed.

You can also refer to this link for details: [Build and Deploy your ASP.NET 5 Application to an Azure Web App](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vs/alm/build/azure/deploy-aspnet5)

Comment: Would that be done as a prebuild step in the tfs build?  The reason I ask is that the tfs build has a single step that gets from source control and kicks off the build.  How do I hook in to that to run a power shell script after the source is pulled down, but before the build starts?

Comment: I'm not sure I have that set of options available to me. I'm using tfs2015 automated build. I do, however, see similar hooks in project.json. Maybe I should try there...

Comment: @FeeFiFoFum The screenshot is for TFS2015 XAML build definition? Are you using it? Or are you using vNext build?

Comment: Good question.  I'm not sure.  In TFS2015 my build is under the 'build definitions' - not under 'XAML definitions' on the left menu on the web portal.  Other teams have created XAML definitions - so maybe I'll try that route.  I'm not sure why there are 2 ways to create builds...?  Is one better than the other?

Comment: @FeeFiFoFum Ok, so you are using the vNext build system. It's a new build system. I have updated my answer for this. Please check it. :)

Comment: Thanks for the update.  Quick follow-up - if that powershell step runs before the VS Build step, how will the source files be there?  It seems to me that the VS Build step is the one that gets the source files from TFS.  Before that step, there won't be anything for the powershell script to act on.

Comment: @FeeFiFoFum VS Build step only builds the source files. The source files are downloaded as soon as the build process is started. So the process is download source file, run powershell and then run vs build.